# How do I keep information in struct after returning from function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I am still a little confused about pointers in connection with structs.
I have a struct which represents a queue. The queue contains an array of queue elements (`containers`).
I now want to access these containers in order to assign values to them. This code is only for `containers[0]` to keep it simple.

How can I access the string at `containers[0]` in `main` after returning from `writeContainer()` function?

The signature of `writeContainer()` is given, so I can't change that.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct qElement {
    char array[55];
    int len;
} container;

typedef struct queue {
    container containers[5];
    int id;
} myq;

int writeContainer(myq anyq, void *buf, int buflen);

int main(void) {
    myq *testq = malloc(sizeof(myq));
    char *mainArray = "hello";

    writeContainer(*testq, mainArray, 6);

    printf("outside Array[0]: %s\n", testq->containers[0].array);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int writeContainer(myq anyq, void *buf, int buflen) {
    container *elem = malloc(sizeof(container));

    // into temp elemnt
    elem->len = buflen;
    memcpy(&elem->array, buf, buflen);

    // into actual queue
    memcpy(&anyq.containers[0], elem, buflen);
    printf("qArray[0]: %s\n", &anyq.containers[0].array);
    printf("exiting function\n");
    free(elem);
    return buflen;
}
```

so the output is:

```
qArray[0]: hello
exiting function
outside Array[0]:
```

but I expected:

```
qArray[0]: hello
exiting function
outside Array[0]: hello
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `doSth`, you are modifying a local copy.  You need to change the signature to `int doSth(myq *anyq, void *buf, int buflen);` and pass `testq`.  (And other changes as needed.)

Comment: thank you, but the signature is given, so i can't change that. Is there any other way ?

Comment: `memcpy(&anyq.containers[0], elem, buflen);` ==> `memcpy(&anyq.containers[0], elem, sizeof *elem);`

Comment: C is pass by value, not pass by reference.  But `writeContainer` takes a `void *`, so you can punch holes in the type system as much as you want.  eg, pass a pointer to a struct in which one of the members is the address of the value you are trying to modify

Comment: You don't need to allocate in `writeContainer()` You don't need to allocate in `main()` either. That is likely where you confusion comes from. Simply declare `myq testq;` all members already have automatic storage. Then call `writeContainer(&testq, mainArray, 6);` and change `int writeContainer(myq *anyq, void *buf, int buflen)` so that you pass the address of `testq`

Comment: How sure are you that you can't change the signature of your `writeContainer`? It states that this function gets a COPY of your `testq`. Aside for the brilliant hack suggested by @WilliamPursell, there is nothing you can do here. My guess is that you misunderstood the assignment...

Comment: Thank you for the compliment, @VladFeinstein   But there is a fine line between "brilliant hack" and "horrible abomination"!

Comment: If you are allowed to modify the struct definitions, you can use another hack that won't damn your soul quite as much.

Comment: After applying David's fix, note that you're _always_ copying to `anyq->containers[0]`. You probably want `myq` to have (e.g.) a `count` element, and copy to `anyq->containers[anyq->count++]`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was typing when you updated the question to say you can't change `writeContainer()` -- which if you really can't change it and have to bastardize the `void*` pointer should at least be renamed `wrongContainer()`...

Comment: Unless you can change the signature of `writeContainer`, the problem is nearly impossible. Any changes you do to `anyq` will _not_ be reflected to the caller. So, it makes the function [effectively] a no-op. Please revisit the original problem statement to verify that you have the correct function signature and correct `typedef` as I believe that you need `myq *anyq` to make any sense [or, as _chqlie_ mentioned the `typedef` should be a _pointer_]. If the problem truly wants the [by value] arg, the problem is broken.

Comment: Are you sure about the typedef for `myq`, it would make sense that it be `typedef struct queue { container containers[5]; int id; } *myq;` instead, which is bad practice but would allow `writeContainer` to perform its task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this prototype for `writeContainer`:

```
int writeContainer(myq anyq, void *buf, int buflen);
```

and the posted definition of `myq`, `writeContainer` cannot be written to have a side effect on the queue passed from `main()` because it is passed by value. The prototype is inconsistent on another aspect: if data from `buf` is only supposed to be read and copied to the container(s), this pointer should be declared as `const void *buf` and its size should be passed as a `size_t buflen`.

There is a `*` missing, either in the prototype or in the `typedef` for `myq`.

Comment: thanks @chqrlie. The missing * for myq was the solution. Makes totally sense now since its a queue with multiple elements.